# SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG FROM TABLE name as parameter problem

Tags: mysql, sql, json, stored-procedures

I want to have a MySQL procedure, that makes SELECT FROM table and return the result in JSON format via JSON_ARRAYAGG, but the table name to be a parameter.

So there is my solution, but it doesn't work when I call it, because the system thinks the parameter is table name. I will be very thankful if someone can help me.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`ME` PROCEDURE `main_list`(
    IN `the_table` CHAR(50)
)
LANGUAGE SQL
DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
BEGIN
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('id', id,'name', NAME)) from the_table;
END
```

The call and error:

```
CALL `main_list`('martin');
/* SQL Error (1146): Table 'my_server.the_table' doesn't exist */
```

Comment: Tablename cannot be taken from variable, use dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

As Akina and gotgn already said you can't use tablename in that way and in some other ise PREPARE Statetemnts for it

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE  PROCEDURE `main_list`(
    IN `the_table` CHAR(50)
)
LANGUAGE SQL
DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
BEGIN
    SET @sql := CONCAT("SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('id', id,'name', NAME)) FROM ",the_table);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```